# Configurar gxmessage: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: configuración, gtk, make

Quiero compilar `gxmessage`, y no puedo configurarlo.

- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gxmessage

Registro donde aparece el error:

```
~/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3 ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

***configure:3330***

```
if test -z "$ac_file"; then :
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
$as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

{ { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
as_fn_error 77 "C compiler cannot create executables
See \`config.log' for more details" "$LINENO" 5; }
else
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }
fi
```

***config.log:***

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU gxmessage configure 3.4.3, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = puppypc23502
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 5.7.2-lxpup64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Sat Jun 13 11:12:52 BST 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3000+
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /root/my-applications/bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt/bin
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2256: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2324: result: /bin/ginstall -c
configure:2335: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2390: result: yes
configure:2539: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2578: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2585: checking for gawk
configure:2601: found /bin/gawk
configure:2612: result: gawk
configure:2623: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2645: result: yes
configure:2674: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2691: result: yes
configure:2820: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2829: result: no
configure:2858: checking for style of include used by make
configure:2886: result: GNU
configure:2957: checking for gcc
configure:2973: found /bin/gcc
configure:2984: result: gcc
configure:3213: checking for C compiler version
configure:3222: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 11.0.1 20210321 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3233: $? = 0
configure:3222: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.0.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-latest --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --disable-libvtv --disable-libssp --disable-libffi --with-system-zlib --without-isl --with-bugurl=https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.0.1 20210321 (experimental) (GCC) 
configure:3233: $? = 0
configure:3222: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3233: $? = 1
configure:3222: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3233: $? = 1
configure:3253: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3275: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
configure:3279: $? = 1
configure:3317: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU gxmessage"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gxmessage"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU gxmessage 3.4.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/gxmessage/"
| #define PACKAGE "gxmessage"
| #define VERSION "3.4.3"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3322: error: in `/root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3':
configure:3324: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PACKAGE_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_PACKAGE_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_PACKAGE_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_PACKAGE_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=set
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/ginstall -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/missing aclocal-1.14'
ALL_LINGUAS=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='gawk'
CATALOGS=''
CATOBJEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATADIRNAME=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GETTEXT_PACKAGE=''
GMOFILES=''
GMSGFMT=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INSTOBJEXT=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTLTOOL_CAVES_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_DESKTOP_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_DIRECTORY_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_EXTRACT=''
INTLTOOL_KBD_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_KEYS_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_MERGE=''
INTLTOOL_OAF_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PERL=''
INTLTOOL_POLICY_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PONG_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_PROP_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SCHEMAS_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SERVER_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SERVICE_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SHEET_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_SOUNDLIST_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_THEME_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_UI_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_UPDATE=''
INTLTOOL_V_MERGE=''
INTLTOOL_V_MERGE_OPTIONS=''
INTLTOOL_XAM_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_XML_NOMERGE_RULE=''
INTLTOOL_XML_RULE=''
INTLTOOL__v_MERGE_0=''
INTLTOOL__v_MERGE_=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/missing makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
MKINSTALLDIRS=''
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_OPTS=''
MSGMERGE=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='gxmessage'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_CFLAGS=''
PACKAGE_LIBS=''
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU gxmessage'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU gxmessage 3.4.3'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gxmessage'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/gxmessage/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.4.3'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
POFILES=''
POSUB=''
PO_IN_DATADIR_FALSE=''
PO_IN_DATADIR_TRUE=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='3.4.3'
XGETTEXT=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /root/documentos/programar/c/gxmessage-3.4.3/install-sh'
intltool__v_merge_options_0=''
intltool__v_merge_options_=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU gxmessage"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gxmessage"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.4.3"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU gxmessage 3.4.3"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/gxmessage/"
#define PACKAGE "gxmessage"
#define VERSION "3.4.3"

configure: exit 77
```

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Comment: Actualiza el compilador gcc, la versión que tienes es experimental. Instala la ultima versión: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: Como está compilando asegurate que tengas los de cabecera .h de la libraría estándar  del c..

Comment: ste error  `.  collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'`  tiene que ver con la librerias del c. No debes tener  instalado el gcc completo.  Aqui está: https://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Gracias, ya con eso me funcionó.

Comment: Lo puse en la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente línea indica que falta el *linker* `ld`:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
```

Para solucionarlo hay que reinstalar `binutils`, por ejemplo el de *Debian*:

- http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza el compilador gcc, la versión que tienes es experimental. Instala la ultima versión: [gcc.gnu.org/install](https://gcc.gnu.org/install).

Como va a compilar, asegurate que tengas los de cabecera .h de la libraría estándar del c. porque este mensaje `fatal error: cannot find 'ld'`  tiene que ver con la librerias del c.

Aqui está: [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org)

Comment: El problema es que en esa página no vienen los binarios, ya estoy entendiendo más el GCC y creo que ya no necesito el GCC doce pero aún así intentaré compilarlo, ahora tengo GCC once.

Comment: Es una referencia, no me puse a profundizar

Comment: Está bien, igual no se entiende mucho ese sitio, para encontrar los binarios hay que buscar bien, además que algunos enlaces redireccionan a la misma página.

Comment: Bueno,  pero te sirvió como punto de inicio al menos. Saludos